# proper use of remove() Function in Python + looping over copyList

Tags: python, list, loops, copy

I am still new to to the coding world and sometimes I struggle with the easiest things ... I wrote the following code which gives me an `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` when I want to exceed it. I am already looping over a copy of the original list that's why I am a bit lost. Here is the code:

```
def revrot(strng, sz):
    if len(strng) == 0 or sz <= 0 or sz > len(strng):
        return ''
    else:
        list = []
        for i in strng:
            list.append(i)
        rest = len(strng)%sz
        for i in range(0,rest):
            list.pop()
        sum = 0
        res = ''
        while len(list) != 0:
            copyList = list[:]
            for i in range(0,sz):
                sum += 1
                if sum%2 == 0:
                    list2 = list[:sz]
                    list2.reverse()
                    res += ''.join(list2)
                    print(res)
                    for i in range(0,sz):
                        list.remove(copyList[i])
                else:
                    res += ''.join(list[1:]) + ''.join(list[0])
                    for i in range(0,sz):
                        list.remove(copyList[i])
    return res
```

The interesting part starts with the `while` loop. I thought I wrote a function that removes the elements from the `list` (in range (0:sz) so at some point the `list` is empty and that's when while stops. 
What I don't get is: why does my `remove()` command throws that ValueError? It works perfectly in the console when I test it separately:

```
copyList
Out[127]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', '9']

for i in range(0,4):
    list.remove(copyList[i])

list
Out[129]: ['5', '6', '7', '7', '9']
```

That's why I am struggling finding the error because it works in the console but not in the editor. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You are deleting items based on the index. But you forgot the fact that when you delete item at index `n`, your item `n+1` becomes `n`.

Here you are deleting items from start of list and keep on moving forward. Where item in the list are also getting swapped backward. So at the point you get `IndexError` exception because the index you hold right now for the item is not at the position you actually expected. It is in the traversed list.

Let's see with an example so that it will make more sense to you:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     print 'index: ', i, 'list:', l
...     del l[i]   # better way to delete item in list based on index
...
index:  0 list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
index:  1 list: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
#                ^ Item at zero index got deleted
#                  Now 2 is at index zero

index:  2 list: [2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
#                ^  ^ This time deleted item 3, because that is at index 2

index:  3 list: [2, 4, 6, 7]
index:  4 list: [2, 4, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

At the end it raises index error because even though the initial length of list was `7`, when `i` was `4` the length of list was `3`

Comment: Thank for your reply, @MoinuddinQuadri. I thought I got rid of that problem by using copyList[i] in the remove command since that way it is not looking for the index of range, instead it goes for copyList[0] = 1 etc. and because I am looping over the copyList and not list the range is staying the original, no?